# Google sheets split with regex or regexextract?

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

Say I have a cell with the following string `1. Finely chop onion & mushroom put in bowl 2. add beef, soy sauce, salt. mix 3. put patties on baking sheet 4. cook 5 mins, flip and bake for another 5 mins.`

I want to split the string so that it is into 4 cells stacked vertically
`1. ...`
`2. ...`
`3. ...`

I tried something like `=split(A1,"\d.")` but that doesn't work. not sure if `regexextract` can do it with one line of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(\d+\.)", "♥$1"), "♥"))
```

[image: 0]