# Is there a way to transform string of names and surnames to seperate rows?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have a string of names and surnames:

```
Name1 Surname1 Name2 Surname2 Name3 Surname3
```

and I want to transform it into separate columns like this:

| Name and surname |
| --- |
| Name1 Surname1 |
| Name2 Surname2 |
| Name3 Surname3 |
| Name4 Surname4 |

I have tried `Paste formatting -> Split text` with a space separator and then `Paste special -> Transposed`, but it separates the first and last name into different columns (columns 6-11):

| Name and surname |
| --- |
| Name1 |
| Surname1 |
| Name2 |
| Surname2 |
| Name3 |
| Surname3 |

I have also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784183/google-sheets-split-with-regex-or-regexextract) post which splits by a task number, but I can't figure out the regex (`(\d+\.)` pattern does not apply to my question. My actual names and surnames don't have any index)

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(\d+\.)", "♥$1"), "♥"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(\S+) (\S+) ","$1 $2"),""))
```

[image]